# How can I use a class before it is declared in c++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to create some conversion functions for two classes by overloading the '=' operator. Here is some code:

```
class Vertex {
public:
    int X, Y;
        // .......
    Vertex& operator= (const VertexF &);   // ERROR, VertexF is not declared
};

class VertexF {
public:
    float X, Y;
        // ......
    VertexF& operator= (const Vertex &);
};
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use forward declaration:

```
class VertexF; // forward declaration of VertexF

class Vertex {
public:
    int X, Y;
        // .......
    Vertex& operator= (const VertexF &);   // ERROR, VertexF is not declared
};

class VertexF {
public:
    float X, Y;
        // ......
    VertexF& operator= (const Vertex &);
};
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think I could do that... I thought it only worked for functions. Thanks, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the classes into separate files and have each reference the other in their respective header files.